# The Date in a Database should be Date type or int(11)?

Tags: sql

When we create a database with a column as date , it can have the type date . But in the startup , I am interning they use int(11) as type to store a date as yyyymmdd eg(20140121) . So is there any advantage of using it or is it just a matter of choice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the DATETIME data type within SQL Server. Not necessarily for performance reasons, but to leverage the RDBMS-specific functionality. For instance, you would have to re-invent a lot of logic just to do basic date math (think DATEDIFF(), DATEADD(), DATEPART() and many other functions. They are obviously tailored to the DATETIME data type and are easy to work with).

you are running into the exact problem that the first question (and my answer) is geared towards. You are looking at 20111201 and 20120131 as dates, and your brain is telling you that should be a difference of 60 days. Well, you're looping through based off of the delta...which is:

20120131 - 20111201 = 8930 (with the inclusive loop it'll be 8931)

In other words, your WHILE loop is executing 8931 times. This is happening because those are integer values and your loop will not jump from 20111231 straight to 20120101.

You integers aren't going to take into account the cap of years and months.

**Additional Information :-**

**Potential data types and their sizes/limitations:**

Decimal(8,0): 5 bytes

Date: 3 bytes, 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31

Int: 4 bytes

**Pros for numeric data type:**

They look pretty?

**Cons for numeric data type:**

1)Requires custom code for handling date operations

2)Requires custom code to manage correct dates (ie, not allowing 20120230 [Feb 30th, 2012])

3)Larger data footprint when compared to the Date data type.

So i hope so know you will be able to know which datatype you should use to store date.
you can define easily by above example.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation . It's weird people use their own types rather than well defined types.

Comment: "I would recommend using the DATETIME data type within SQL Server." - Nope. If you want a date use the Date datatype.

Comment: "yes i would also recommend to use of DATETIME datetype in within SQL server."

Comment: "This is difference between DATETIME and DATETIME2 in sql Serever"

Comment: The difference is the time precision and the range of dates that DATETIME2 can store. The new DATETIME2 data type can hold a range of dates from 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 while DATETIME holds the date range from 1753-01-01 to 9999-12-31. Another benefit of this data type is the precision in which it records time. DATETIME2 is accurate to within 100 nanoseconds whereas DATETIME is accurate to within 3/1000 of a second. The following script compares the values that the DATETIME and the DATETIME2 data-types can hold.

Answer (score 1):

Integer encoded dates (e.g. 20140121) are common in warehouse databases.

Whether it's a good idea depends somewhat upon which RBDMS you are using. In some instances they use less space than an equivalent datetime datatype, and they are readable in a raw data form.

For example, it used to be the recommended approach in SQL Server prior to version 2008. But in SQL Server 2008+ there is a 3 byte pure date type which takes less space and is also easily readable as a date.

Comment: But shouldn't be date type natural for all type of comparisons??

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any advantages od using a plain integer apart from the rather dubious ability to accept invalid dates like -19000233.

The advantages are that in most DBMSes you can use a rich variety of *accurate* date functions. For instance in DB2 you can say

```
WHERE PAYMENT_DATE + 30 DAYS > ORDER_DATE
```

to find out which customers are reluctant to hand over the money in a timely fashion.